# Extract int digits and float number from a python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string for example:

```
str1 = "'107.8X98x3.75'"
[107.8, 98, 3.75]
str2 = 'L=130.5mm;L=90mm'
[130.5, 90]
str3 = '圓278.5x15t 304'
[278.5, 15, 304]
```

I know how to extract by int and float, but I don't want to miss which the numbers appear.

Comment: I am not sure why this is downgraded while this title is visited more than 2k.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about regular expressions?

**Example**

```
>>> import re
>>> str1="107.8X98x3.75"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', str1)
['107.8', '98', '3.75']
```

Comment: I'am adding some explanation for regex: r for raw expression (I am not sure this is necessary), \d+ some digits whether followed by (<regex2>) or not due to ( ) '?' (0 or 1 option). <regex2> is '?:' uncapture this group enclosed by ( ), '\.' is literal dot rather than use dot as metacharacter, followed by \d+ digits then it becomes ".123".