# How to find a particular combination of string and float/int?

Tags: python

I have the following question. As input I have a datename, which must have a certain nomenclature, like

1. Footballfield_01_CampNou_108m_Length_68.5_Width
2. Footballfield_02_Bernabeau_105m_Length_68.5_Width

For the width the meter is missing. But I cannot change the name and have to work with this. My task now is to write a code, which extracts only the length and the width from the data name to calculate the area on it. I have had several ideas, but these are error-prone and not robust enough. My idea now is based on knowing that I have an integer value (length) and a float value (width). I want to write a code that finds the float value and the integer value in the string and assigns them to the width and length but I can't find any way, can anyone help me?

Comment: try, `data = dataname.split("_")`. this will give you a list of fields. Assuming you have a standard nomenclature, `data[3]` will be the length, and `data[5]` will be the width. You may have to clean-up the `m` units for lengths before you actually perform any area-related operations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract int digits and float number from a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840685/extract-int-digits-and-float-number-from-a-python-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to solve this task:

```
import re
//somehow get the input_list
for entry in input_list:
    match = re.match(r"\w+_\d+_\w+_(\d+)m_Length_(([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)_Width", entry)
    length, width, _ = match.groups()
    length = int(length)
    width = float(width)
```

going into more detail about the regex:

- `\w+` matches alphabetical characters
- `\d+` matches digits
- `_` matches `_` literally
- `()` around a some regex captures that value to return
- `(([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)` is caputuring the floating point part as explained here [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

https://regex101.com/r/8BOvMh/1 example working online